# Trouble using explode() with mutiple delimiters and loops in PHP

Tags: php, loops, explode, delimiter

My string is as such

```
$items = "2,1/3,5/2,5/3,2";
```

The slash (/) separated values are each item order.

The comma (,) separated values are item ID's and quantity.

I want to create a loop that separates the / values and then separates the , values but I'm having trouble doing so.

```
$order_array = explode('/', $items);
    $order = '';
    foreach ($order_array as $item_array) {
        $item = explode(',', $item_array);
        foreach ($item as $key) {
            echo 'Item ID '.$key[0].' QTY'.$key[1];

        }
    }
```

Comment: What's going wrong then?

Comment: You have a syntax error here: should be `echo 'Item ID '.$key[0].' QTY '.$key[1];`

Comment: Code looks good, we can only guess that that's the problem.

Comment: echo 'Item ID ' . $key[0] . ' QTY ' . $key[1];

Comment: Apart from the typo in echo line. There does not seem to be an error. Another thing that you should change is echoing only on last iteration. Currently you are printing array on every iteration.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if i am not wrong below is the code you are looking for.

```
<?php
$items = "2,1/3,5/2,5/3,2";
$order_array = explode('/', $items);
$order = '';
foreach ($order_array as $item_array)
{
    $item = explode(',', $item_array);
    echo 'Item ID '.$item[0].' QTY '.$item[1] .'<br />';
}
```

Because what you were doing is get `$item` in `foreach` loop and accessing `$key` as `$key[0]` which does not exists so it will throw error.

Answer (score 1):

After you have done

```
$item = explode(',', $item_array);
```

then you have your values in $item[0] and $item[1]

Remove the inner

```
foreach ($item as $key) {
            echo 'Item ID '.$key[0].' 'QTY '.$key[1];

        }
```

Print the values as

```
echo 'Item ID '.$item[0].' QTY '.$item[1];
```

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned before you have a syntax error in the echo statement with the extra single quote. You also don't need the innermost foreach loop.

```
$order_array = explode('/', $items);
$order = '';
foreach ($order_array as $item_array) {
    $item = explode(',', $item_array);
    echo 'Item ID '.$item[0]. 'QTY '.$item[1];


}
```